# Span of a set is a subspace of a span of another set

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I have two sets of vectors S1 and S2. These sets are subsets of a vector space V, which has both the base and the dimension unknown. Now, I don't know the elements of sets S1 and S2 and I need to prove that if S1 is a subset of S2, then span(S1) is a subspace of span(S2).

I was hoping that I could get some hints, since I am really confused by this question. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hints**

- **Subset**: if $S_1 \subset S_2$, then $\mbox{span}(S_1) \subset \mbox{span}(S_2)$; why (*see below*)?
- **Subspace**: for any $S \subset V$, $\mbox{span}(S)$ is a subspace of $V$ (either by definition or easily shown; it is the *smallest* subspace of $V$ containing $S$).

---

More explicit after comments.

If $S_1 = \left\{ \color{blue}{\vec s_1,\vec s_2,\ldots,\vec s_k}\right\}$ and if $S_2 = \left\{ \color{blue}{\vec s_1,\vec s_2,\ldots,\vec s_k},\color{red}{\vec s_{k+1},\ldots,\vec s_n}\right\}$ so $S_1 \subset S_2 \subset V$, then:
$$\mbox{span}(S_1) = \left\{ \left. \sum_{i=1}^k \alpha_i\vec s_i \;\right| \color{blue}{\alpha_1 , \ldots , \alpha_k} \in \mathbb{R} \right\}$$
and (with $n \ge k$):
$$\mbox{span}(S_2) = \left\{ \left. \sum_{i=1}^n \alpha_i\vec s_i \;\right|\color{blue}{ \alpha_1 , \ldots, \alpha_k}, \color{red}{\alpha_{k+1} , \ldots, \alpha_n} \in \mathbb{R} \right\}$$
Now clearly $\mbox{span}(S_1) \subset \mbox{span}(S_2)$ since for any $\vec x \in S_1$ you also have $\vec x \in S_2$ by taking the same first $k$ coefficients $\color{blue}{\alpha_i}$ ($\color{blue}{1 \le i \le k}$) and setting the others $0$ ($\color{red}{\alpha_j = 0}$ for $\color{red}{k < j \le n}$).

Now you only need that $\mbox{span}(S_1)$ forms a vector space but that's probably something you've already showed for an arbitrary set of the form $\mbox{span}(S)$ with $S \subset V$.

If not: verify that it's non-empty and closed under addition and scalar multiplication, which should be clear from the ("linear combination") definition of span.